# UE5.3 (win10 platform build from source) packaging failed

Tags: unreal-engine5

The solution configurations in vs2022 is debug editor, project is suntemple.

Error:
LogBlueprint: Error: [Compiler] Cannot use the editor function "Play" in this runtime Blueprint. Only for use in Editor Utility Blueprints and Blutilities. from Source: /Game/Maps/SunTemple.SunTemple:PersistentLevel.SunTemple

Error picture:

[image]

settings:

[image]

settings:

[image]

settings:

[image]

settings:

[image]

settings:

[image]